# Identify multiple regex matches in a single string and get substring for each match

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to find strings with regex pattern.
For example:

```
# header ## smaller header
```

I would like to find two string set as follows.

```
# header
## smaller header
```

So I make the regex pattern as follows.

```
pattern = re.compile("(?:^#+|\s#+)\s")
```

With this pattern, I can find # header.

```
# header
```

But I can't find the string such as `## smaller header`

How can I make the regex so that find two set of strings?

Comment: Can you post the full code, so we can reproduce? [mcve]

Comment: It works for me. What is exactly your string, I tried both one liners ("# header ## smaller header") and "# header \n## smaller header"

Comment: I just understood. You must use match, which retrieve the first match only. You have to use findall or finditer, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"#+(\s\w+)+")
for m in p.finditer('# header ## smaller header'):
    print(m.group())
```

which outputs

```
# header 
## smaller header
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       import re
       pattern = re.compile("#+[\s\w]+")
       a = re.findall(pattern,'# header ## smaller header')
       print (*a,sep="\n")
```